# How to implement a cookie popup once per session with pure javascript or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

I want to implement cookie policy with pop up that shows only once.

The problem is that I don't want to use any .js framework to do that and I don't know how to make pop up show up only once per session.

I searched the forum and found this:
[Need single popup for each session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978324/need-single-popup-for-each-session)
But I still can't make it work.

Thank you for help in advance. Especially because I am a beginner.

Comment: Try some solutions and then ask more specific questions regarding actual implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to implement cookie in javascript. Please refer the below javascript code :

```
var getCookieValues = new RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)' + ('cookieName')
                     .replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&') + '=([^;]*)')
                     .exec(document.cookie);
var g = (getCookieValues === null)?"NULL":getCookieValues[1];

if(g === "NULL"){
  // Show you popup
  document.cookie ="cookieName=views;session;path=/";
}
```